# Fees when using leverage

Tags: exchanges, exchange-fees

I have been wondering how trading fees are actually calculated e.g. [Kraken](https://www.kraken.com/en-us/help/fees) takes 0,35% of every trade. Does this fee apply both when I buy bitcoins and later when I sell them?

Furthermore if I choose to open a position of lets say $100, and leverage on 1:3, is the fee calculated as $100 * 0,0035 or as $300 * 0,0035?

Thanks in advance